# Designate an arbitrary folder as Android assets?

Tags: android, eclipse, resources

It seems that the Android resource compiler does not take into account linked folders (in Eclipse sense) in the assets folder. Question - is there a way to forcibly designate a folder of my choice as Android project assets?

Short of copying or hardlinking into project assets, I mean.

Comment: See my answer to 
[How to link assets/www folder in Eclipse / Phonegap / Android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843181/how-to-link-assets-www-folder-in-eclipse-phonegap-android-project/7223531#7223531)

Comment: @phatblat : Eclipse accepts the settings and does a build. But apk file does not contain the files inside linked folder. Is there any other setting that is required? I am using Eclipes 3.7.0 on MacOS X Snow Leopard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved via filsystem-level hardlinks.

Answer (score 1):

> Question - is there a way to forcibly
>   designate a folder of my choice as
>   Android project assets?

The `aapt` command takes an `-A` switch ("additional directory in which to find raw asset files"). How you customize Eclipse's calls to `aapt` to use this switch is beyond my expertise.