# How to link assets/www folder in Eclipse / Phonegap / Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am working on a PhoneGap app that is supposed to run on iOS and Android. My folder structure looks like this:

```
+-+-[app folder]
  |
  +-[android] (contains Eclipse workspace and project files)
  |
  +-[iOS] (contains XCode project files)
  |
  +-[www] (contains all html, js, css etc. files for the actual app)
```

It's easy to reference the www folder in the XCode project, everything there works fine.

However, creating a link to the www folder in Eclipse doesn't work as expected: I used 'Import -> Filesystem' to create the link under the existing assets folder and everything seemed to work fine. But the files are not getting copied to the apk during the build step.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Were you successful with answer you've marked as accepted? For me it seems 'www' has to be put into '$PROJECT_DIR', otherwise I get infinite number of alert views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For windows use this command `mklink /D link-name target-folder` and for linux/mac use `ln` to create a source link. Both works for me.

Comment: I had to do it in a Windows command prompt with administrator privileges to have it working properly.

Comment: @JulienBérubé yes i forgot to mention that part, thanks for that.

Comment: A solution that doesn't involve mucking around in the filesystem outside of Eclipse would be far preferable.  Does one exist?

Comment: Dying out here - no cleaner solution yet?

Comment: @Danjah haven't tried anything as this works fine. Do you have any specific issues??

Comment: @dhaval Only that when imaging a new machine it's another specific thing I have to do in the fs, whereas an Eclipse solution that might apply to many or no projects, or be part of a project config, is what I'd hoped for. I'm new to Eclipse, and so I read this just now: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/771437/ -- does this sound like an alternative do you think?

Comment: @Danjah I have not tried using the eclipse variable so sure whether it will work or not, not to forget we need the source folder in the `/assets` directory and not at the regular source location

Comment: this solution is not compatible with source control or common sense -1

Comment: @jheriko you do realize that I answered this a year back!!! Also please suggest the solution you are using which matches the common sense and source control. I am using `git` and it works fine.

Comment: it may work, but the idea is platform dependent and external to the files that are part of your project. keeping everything 'obvious' but not 'hiding' things in the filesystem is generally good practice and ensures compatibility across all source control you may encounter. git is great, but its very modern and little used commercially - cvs, p4, svn etc. are all nastier to varying degrees and in their own ways. the common sense i was referring to is perhaps not so common - just that data should be treated as such regardless as to its nature (i.e. be encoded obviously where suitable).

Answer (score 15):

This can be accomplished creating a "Linked Folder" resource in Eclipse. It's essentially the same thing as what Xcode creates when you drag any file or folder into your project and tell it to create references - just nowhere near as easy.

The ADT Eclipse plugin expects an "assets" folder at the top level of your project, so we're going to create an /assets linked folder that references ../www, sitting right next to your project folder.

1. File menu > New > Folder
2. Folder name: **assets**
3. Click **Advanced >>**
4. Select: Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)

   - *You can use Browse to select the www folder and you're done, but this option creates the link using a full path which will usually break on other team members' systems*
5. Click **Variables...**
6. New

   1. Name: **SIBLING_WWW_FOLDER**
   2. Location: **${PROJECT_LOC}/../www**
7. OK
8. Select **SIBLING_WWW_FOLDER** and click OK
9. Finish

Comment: Didn't the poster do this? Just in another way.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It works fine for editing, but I don't think that the Android build tools follow the Eclipse links when they bundle the assets into the .apk file.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. The files are not getting bundled in the apk file. Must be some other setting.. :-( Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. As the files are not copied in the .apk, I found that the mklink /D option in windows works well.

Comment: Also didn't work for me! I can't find a setting to get it to work. :-\

Comment: it does work when you try to link assets to ../www. It doesn't when a link is done between assets/www and ../www

Comment: For all of those that doesn't work it. You just **cut/move** your current assets folder and **paste** it in ../, rename it (if you want follow step by step the answer) as www and then **follow all the steps**. It does work and it's great when you work with a team using control version.

Comment: Yep, does not work as written in the answer.  The comments suggesting possible workarounds are not clear enough to follow.

Comment: Worked for me after adjusting <content src="your index.html here" /> in res/xml/config.xml. Btw, the linked resource is saved in the .project file so this will have to be added to version control if collaborators are to benefit from it.

Comment: This worked for me. The key is: 1. Make assets folder itself a link (not make a subfolder of assets a link). 2. Clean the project and/or delete the bin/apk file. Maybe restart eclipse too just to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how does it work in MacOS but I guess you can create a symbolic link with ln, putting your www folder inside Eclipse's assets. I do it both in Windows and Linux and work ok.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this solution, it would definitely work on OSX.   However, I should have mentioned that I am looking for a way to do this in Eclipse without filesystem-links, because anyone checking the project out of our svn would have to set the links up by hand.

Comment: Umh... something like this? http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648493/load-webview-with-html-file-linked-to-assets-folder