# Phonegap iOS/Android - Linking www folder

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, cordova

I am trying to use a single /www folder to write a phonegap app for both iOS and Android,

My folder structure is something like this :

Code/Android/Eclipse project files

Code/iOS/xCode project files

Code/www/index.html, phonegap.js,etc.

Now i am trying within eclipse to link to the external www folder, i have trier several methods including the one proposed here : [How to link assets/www folder in Eclipse / Phonegap / Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843181/how-to-link-assets-www-folder-in-eclipse-phonegap-android-project) without any success :

When starting the app in an android virtual device reports an error if the www folder containing the index.html is not actually in Android/Project/Assets/..

Any idea how to make this work with links? Or is there maybe a way to tell eclipse to copy files to a new location upon building the project?

Thank you

PS : I will be mainly on windows so symbolic links are not an option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved the same issue on windows with following command:

`cd c:\code\app\android\assets\`

`mklink /D www c:\code\app\www`

This worked for me in Windows. On Mac you can either use xcode folder referencing or `ln` command for the same.

(edit 3/14/2013) Windows 7: Make sure to run the command prompt **as administrator**

Comment: +1 I am most likely to use this solution myself - but could you tell me why not use hard links?

Comment: hard links are basically actual files, as the /www folder needs to be under the /assets for android or /<project folder> for iOS, I can not use the same source for both, so had to keep the source one level up and use the simlink instead

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to this is to use SVN externals in each directory for iOS and Android to pull in a common WWW directory.